# How to keep focus on an element after recompose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I have a custom component in my Compose Desktop app, which can have the focus:

```
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
var focused by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Row(modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    .focusRequester(focusRequester)
    .onFocusChanged { state -> focused = state.isFocused }
```

This works as you'd expect. However, when I add a border based on `focused` state, it breaks:

```
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
var focused by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    .focusRequester(focusRequester)
    .onFocusChanged { state -> focused = state.isFocused }
    .border(if (focused) 1.dp else 0.dp, MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
```

From what I can tell, the recompose actually causes the `onFocusedChanged` to fire again with `isFocused = false`. So that's the problem, not the remembering of the `focused` property itself.

How can my component keep the focus after recomposing to draw the border?

Comment: What do you mean by "it breaks"? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @PylypDukhov That is explained in the second to last paragraph. If it's not clear, please be specific so I can update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `interactionSource.collectIsFocusedAsState()` instead of the
`onFocusChanged` modifier.

Something like:

```
val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
val focused by interactionSource.collectIsFocusedAsState()

    Row(Modifier
         // add focusRequester modifier before the focusable (or even in the parent)
        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
        .focusable(interactionSource = interactionSource)
        .border(if (focused) 1.dp else 0.dp, MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
```